# Microsoft Bot Framework send message without having an user talk to the bot

Tags: javascript, botframework, bots

I need to make a bot to send a message each ten minutes using Javascript. I'm using Microsoft Bot Framework, this is the entry code:

```
const restify = require('restify');
const botbuilder = require('botbuilder');

var adapter = new botbuilder.BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});

let server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
    console.log(`\n${server.name} listening to ${server.url}`);
    console.log(`\nGet Bot Framework Emulator: https://aka.ms/botframework-emulator`);
});

server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (turnContext) => {
        if (turnContext.activity.type === 'message') {            
            const text = turnContext.activity.text;
            await turnContext.sendActivity(`You just said: ${ text }`);
        }
    });
});
```

Basically that responds with "You just said: x" to whatever the person talking to the bot said.

What I need is the bot to be in group in Skype and send a message each ten minutes.

However, in my example, the server awaits for a POST to /api/messages, then it uses the adapter to process that request and fires the "sendActivity" method from the turnContext, which comes from the processActivity method.

How can I just send a message at a fixed interval, and ignore all messages/mentions.

Comment: Not sure if this will work but have you looked at proactive messages? I would think you could use the methods here but have the message sent on a timer instead of based on a notification. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript

Comment: I've been looking for a way to do this, but example for proactive messages provided by Microsoft documents depend on the user contacting the bot at least once so it can capture and store the conversation id for further interaction.
If I understand this question correctly (and it would be what I'm looking for) @nick is trying to contact users regardless of a previous interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is called **proactive messaging**. You can have a look at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript) and [the sample it references](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages) to better understand how to do this.

If you want your proactive messages to be triggered by a timer then you can run the timer on a thread in your bot, though it's generally recommended to have the timer running externally.

To disable messaging for your bot, simply choose that option in your [channel configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-skype). I'm not sure how you'll retrieve the conversation ID if you disable messaging, though.

[image]

If you still want your bot to receive messages but just don't want to reply to them, simply edit the part of your bot code that responds to the condition `turnContext.activity.type === 'message'`.

Please keep in mind that Skype bot features may become increasingly limited. You should see an official message in your Skype channel configuration that says:

> As of October 31, 2019 the Skype channel will no longer be accepting new Bot registrations. Current Skype bots will continue to run uninterrupted.

Comment: Thanks, I used proactive messaging and it works! I'll just put the GET on a timer on another process. I'm having a problem though each time I push changes to the bot it stops the server to reload the changes, and therefore I need to tag the bot again to get it working. I need to persist the reference of the chat in the database to fix this right?

Comment: Yes, bots shouldn't store anything in their own memory that needs to persist between turns. Conventional bot state uses the conversation ID and/or user ID from the incoming activity as a key to access the right data from storage, but your proactive messaging bot won't be reacting to incoming activities so you'll need to define your own type of state storage with a constant key.